# How to throw error on UI on after update Trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger

My requirement is to throw an error on top of the UI, if 'SAP Error' equals to true

I am updating this 'SAP Error'boolean from a future callout method

Triggercode

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (after insert, after update) {

    Set<Id> accLst = new Set<Id>();
    
   if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter){
    for(Account accNew: Trigger.New) {
        system.debug('CC ID' + accNew);
        accLst.add(accNew.Id);
    }
     SAPIntegration.Integrationsap(accLst);
   }
    else if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isAfter){
        for(Account accNew: Trigger.New) {
            if(accNew.SAP_Error__c == true) {
                System.debug('sap error ' + accNew.SAP_Error__c);
               // Trigger.New.     throw error here..How???
            }
        }
    
    }
    

}
```

Integrationcode

```
global class SAPIntegration{

  @future(callout = true)
  global static void Integrationsap(Set<Id> acclst) {
      
    List<Account> DelAccLst= [select id, IsPersonAccount,Business_Partner_Grouping__c,Business_Partner_Role__c,FirstName,
                              LastName,BillingAddress,BillingPostalCode,BillingCity, Phone, Preferred_Contact_Method__c,
                              Registration_No__c,Trade_License_No__c,Preferred_Language__pc,TRN__c, Salutation,Nationality__pc,
                              PersonMobilePhone, PersonEmail, Preferred_Contact_Method__pc,Emirates_ID_Number__pc,Passport_No__pc,
                              Passport_No__c,
                              Preferred_Language__c,Search_Term__c,Nationality__c,BillingStreet  from account where id in : acclst];

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setHeader('X-API-Key', '19cc8980-xxxxxx261-0242ac120002');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    String endpoint = 'https://apiservices.qproperties.coxxxxx';
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setEndpoint(endpoint); 
    req.setTimeout(120000);
    map<String,String> mapOfCountryNameToCountrycode = new map<String, String>(); 
    map<String,String> mapOfLanguageNameToLanguagecode = new map<String, String>();
   

    // retrieve metadata values to get Country code of the respective country names 
    Map<String, Account_Nationality_Code__mdt> countryName = Account_Nationality_Code__mdt.getAll();
    for(Account_Nationality_Code__mdt country : countryName.values()){
        
       mapOfCountryNameToCountrycode.put(country.MasterLabel, country.DeveloperName);
       
    }
        Map<String, Account_Language_Code__mdt> languageName = Account_Language_Code__mdt.getAll();
    for(Account_Language_Code__mdt language : languageName.values()){
        
       mapOfLanguageNameToLanguagecode.put(language.MasterLabel, language.DeveloperName);
       
    }
     List<Account> accntLst = new List<Account>();
     String jsonData = '';
     if(!DelAccLst.isEmpty()){
            JSONGenerator jsonGen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
            for(Account con : DelAccLst){
                jsonGen.writeStartObject();
            
                if(!con.IsPersonAccount) {
                jsonGen.writeObjectField('BusinessPartnerCategory','1');
                    if(con.Business_Partner_Grouping__c != null) {
                   jsonGen.writeObjectField('BusinessPartnerGrouping',con.Business_Partner_Grouping__c);
                    }
                    else {
                     jsonGen.writeObjectField('BusinessPartnerGrouping','Z051');   
                    }
                jsonGen.writeFieldName('to_BusinessPartnerRole');
                jsonGen.writeStartArray();
                jsonGen.writeStartObject();
                    if(con.Business_Partner_Role__c != null) {
                  jsonGen.writeObjectField('BusinessPartnerRole',con.Business_Partner_Role__c);
                    }
                    else {
                     jsonGen.writeObjectField('BusinessPartnerRole','ZTR601');   
                    }
                
                jsonGen.writeEndObject();
                jsonGen.writeEndArray();
                    if(con.FirstName != null) {
                 jsonGen.writeObjectField('FirstName',con.FirstName);
                    }
                    else {
                     jsonGen.writeObjectField('FirstName','BP Odata Service');   
                    }
                    if(con.LastName != null) {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('LastName',con.LastName);
                    }
                    else {
                     jsonGen.writeObjectField('LastName','SFDC');   
                    }
                    
                     if(con.Preferred_Language__c != null) {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('CorrespondenceLanguage',mapOfLanguageNameToLanguagecode.get(con.Preferred_Language__c));
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('Language',mapOfLanguageNameToLanguagecode.get(con.Preferred_Language__c));
                    }
                    else {
                     jsonGen.writeObjectField('CorrespondenceLanguage','EN');  
                     jsonGen.writeObjectField('Language','EN');
                    }
                    
                     if(con.Search_Term__c != null) {
                   jsonGen.writeObjectField('SearchTerm1',con.Search_Term__c);
                    }
                    else {
                     jsonGen.writeObjectField('SearchTerm1','Test');
                    }
                    
                     jsonGen.writeObjectField('FormOfAddress','0003');
                    if(con.Nationality__c != null) {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('NameCountry',mapOfCountryNameToCountrycode.get(con.Nationality__c));
                    }
                    else {
                     jsonGen.writeObjectField('NameCountry','AE');
                    }
                   
                jsonGen.writeFieldName('to_BusinessPartnerAddress');
                jsonGen.writeStartArray();
                jsonGen.writeStartObject();
                 if(con.BillingStreet != null) {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('StreetName',con.BillingStreet);
                    }
                    else {
                     jsonGen.writeObjectField('StreetName','Park Street');
                    } 
                    
                    if(con.BillingStreet != null) {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('HouseNumber','hno');
                   // jsonGen.writeObjectField('HouseNumber',con.BillingStreet);
                    }
                    else {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('HouseNumber','H.No.');
                    } 
                    
                    if(con.BillingPostalCode != null) {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('PostalCode',con.BillingPostalCode);
                    }
                    else {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('PostalCode','12456');
                    } 
                    
                     
                    if(con.BillingCity != null) {
                   jsonGen.writeObjectField('CityName',con.BillingCity);
                    }
                    else {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('CityName','Abu Dhabi');
                    } 
                    
                     if(con.Nationality__c != null) {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('Country',mapOfCountryNameToCountrycode.get(con.Nationality__c));
                    }
                    else {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('Country','AE');
                    } 
                    
                     if(con.BillingPostalCode != null) {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('POBox',con.BillingPostalCode);
                    }
                    else {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('POBox','392934');
                    } 
                jsonGen.writeFieldName('to_MobilePhoneNumber');
                jsonGen.writeStartArray();
                jsonGen.writeStartObject();
                     if(con.Phone != null) {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('PhoneNumber',con.Phone);
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('IsDefaultPhoneNumber',true);
                    }
                    else {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('PhoneNumber','12040939');
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('IsDefaultPhoneNumber',false);
                    } 
               
              
                jsonGen.writeEndObject();
                jsonGen.writeEndArray();
                jsonGen.writeFieldName('to_PhoneNumber');
                jsonGen.writeStartArray();
                jsonGen.writeStartObject();
                     if(con.Phone != null) {
                     jsonGen.writeObjectField('PhoneNumber',con.Phone);
                     jsonGen.writeObjectField('IsDefaultPhoneNumber',true);
                    }
                    else {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('PhoneNumber','12040939');
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('IsDefaultPhoneNumber',false);
                    } 
               
                
                jsonGen.writeEndObject();
                jsonGen.writeEndArray();
                jsonGen.writeFieldName('to_EmailAddress');
                jsonGen.writeStartArray();
                jsonGen.writeStartObject();
                Contact cont = [Select Id, Email, Passport_No__c from Contact where AccountId=:con.Id];
                    if(cont != null) {
                        jsonGen.writeObjectField('EmailAddress',cont.Email);
                        jsonGen.writeObjectField('IsDefaultEmailAddress',true);
                    }
                    else{
                        jsonGen.writeObjectField('EmailAddress','test@gmail.com');
                        jsonGen.writeObjectField('IsDefaultEmailAddress',false);
                    }
                
                jsonGen.writeEndObject();
                jsonGen.writeEndArray();
                    if(con.Preferred_Contact_Method__c != null) {
                      //jsonGen.writeObjectField('PrfrdCommMediumType',con.Preferred_Contact_Method__c);
                         jsonGen.writeObjectField('PrfrdCommMediumType','INT');
                    }
                    else {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('PrfrdCommMediumType','INT');
                    } 
               
                jsonGen.writeEndObject();
                jsonGen.writeEndArray();
                jsonGen.writeFieldName('to_BuPaIdentification');
                jsonGen.writeStartArray();
                      if(cont != null) {
                jsonGen.writeStartObject();
                jsonGen.writeObjectField('BPIdentificationType','FS0002');
                jsonGen.writeObjectField('BPIdentificationNumber',cont.Passport_No__c);
                     if(con.Nationality__c != null) {
                      jsonGen.writeObjectField('Country',mapOfCountryNameToCountrycode.get(con.Nationality__c));
                    }
                    else {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('Country','AE');
                    } 
                jsonGen.writeEndObject();  
                }
                if(con.TRN__c != null) {
                jsonGen.writeStartObject();
                jsonGen.writeObjectField('BPIdentificationType','FS0003');
                jsonGen.writeObjectField('BPIdentificationNumber',con.TRN__c);
                     if(con.Nationality__c != null) {
                      jsonGen.writeObjectField('Country',mapOfCountryNameToCountrycode.get(con.Nationality__c));
                    }
                    else {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('Country','AE');
                    } 
               
                jsonGen.writeEndObject();
                }
                if(con.Trade_License_No__c != null) {
                jsonGen.writeStartObject();
                jsonGen.writeObjectField('BPIdentificationType','FS0004');
                jsonGen.writeObjectField('BPIdentificationNumber',con.Trade_License_No__c);
                     if(con.Nationality__c != null) {
                      jsonGen.writeObjectField('Country',mapOfCountryNameToCountrycode.get(con.Nationality__c));
                    }
                    else {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('Country','AE');
                    } 
                jsonGen.writeEndObject();  
                }
              
                
                jsonGen.writeEndArray();
            }
                
                else {
                  jsonGen.writeObjectField('BusinessPartnerCategory','1');
                jsonGen.writeObjectField('BusinessPartnerGrouping','Z051');

                jsonGen.writeFieldName('to_BusinessPartnerRole');
                jsonGen.writeStartArray();
                jsonGen.writeStartObject();
                jsonGen.writeObjectField('BusinessPartnerRole','ZTR601');
                jsonGen.writeEndObject();
                jsonGen.writeEndArray();
                    if(con.FirstName != null) {
                 jsonGen.writeObjectField('FirstName',con.FirstName);
                    }
                    else {
                     jsonGen.writeObjectField('FirstName','BP Odata Service');   
                    }
                    if(con.LastName != null) {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('LastName',con.LastName);
                    }
                    else {
                     jsonGen.writeObjectField('LastName','SFDC');   
                    }
                    
                     if(con.Preferred_Language__pc != null) {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('CorrespondenceLanguage',mapOfLanguageNameToLanguagecode.get(con.Preferred_Language__pc));
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('Language',mapOfLanguageNameToLanguagecode.get(con.Preferred_Language__pc));
                    }
                    else {
                     jsonGen.writeObjectField('CorrespondenceLanguage','EN');  
                     jsonGen.writeObjectField('Language','EN');
                    }
                    
                     if(con.Search_Term__c != null) {
                   jsonGen.writeObjectField('SearchTerm1',con.Search_Term__c);
                    }
                    else {
                     jsonGen.writeObjectField('SearchTerm1','Test');
                    }
                    
                    if(con.Salutation == 'Mr.'){
                jsonGen.writeObjectField('FormOfAddress','0002');
                    }
                    else if(con.Salutation == 'Ms.' || con.Salutation == 'Mrs.'){
                jsonGen.writeObjectField('FormOfAddress','0001');
                    }
                     else{
                jsonGen.writeObjectField('FormOfAddress','0001');
                    }

                    if(con.Nationality__pc != null) {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('NameCountry',mapOfCountryNameToCountrycode.get(con.Nationality__pc));
                    }
                    else {
                     jsonGen.writeObjectField('NameCountry','AE');
                    }
                   
                jsonGen.writeFieldName('to_BusinessPartnerAddress');
                jsonGen.writeStartArray();
                jsonGen.writeStartObject();
                 if(con.BillingStreet != null) {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('StreetName',con.BillingStreet);
                    }
                    else {
                     jsonGen.writeObjectField('StreetName','Park Street');
                    } 
                    
                    if(con.BillingStreet != null) {
                    //jsonGen.writeObjectField('HouseNumber','hno');
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('HouseNumber',con.BillingStreet);
                    }
                    else {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('HouseNumber','H.No.');
                    } 
                    
                    if(con.BillingPostalCode != null) {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('PostalCode',con.BillingPostalCode);
                    }
                    else {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('PostalCode','12456');
                    } 
                    
                    if(con.BillingCity != null) {
                   jsonGen.writeObjectField('CityName',con.BillingCity);
                    }
                    else {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('CityName','Abu Dhabi');
                    } 
                    
                     if(con.Nationality__pc != null) {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('Country',mapOfCountryNameToCountrycode.get(con.Nationality__pc));
                    }
                    else {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('Country','AE');
                    } 
                    
                     if(con.BillingPostalCode != null) {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('POBox',con.BillingPostalCode);
                    }
                    else {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('POBox','392934');
                    } 
                jsonGen.writeFieldName('to_MobilePhoneNumber');
                jsonGen.writeStartArray();
                jsonGen.writeStartObject();
                     if(con.PersonMobilePhone != null) {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('PhoneNumber',con.PersonMobilePhone);
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('IsDefaultPhoneNumber',true);
                    }
                    else {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('PhoneNumber','12040939');
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('IsDefaultPhoneNumber',false);
                    } 
               
                jsonGen.writeEndObject();
                jsonGen.writeEndArray();
                jsonGen.writeFieldName('to_PhoneNumber');
                jsonGen.writeStartArray();
                jsonGen.writeStartObject();
                     if(con.PersonMobilePhone != null) {
                     jsonGen.writeObjectField('PhoneNumber',con.PersonMobilePhone);
                     jsonGen.writeObjectField('IsDefaultPhoneNumber',true);
                    }
                    else {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('PhoneNumber','12040939');
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('IsDefaultPhoneNumber',false);
                    } 
               
                jsonGen.writeEndObject();
                jsonGen.writeEndArray();
                jsonGen.writeFieldName('to_EmailAddress');
                jsonGen.writeStartArray();
                jsonGen.writeStartObject();
                     if(con.PersonEmail != null) {
                     jsonGen.writeObjectField('EmailAddress',con.PersonEmail);
                     jsonGen.writeObjectField('IsDefaultEmailAddress',true);
                    }
                    else {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('EmailAddress','test@gmail.com');
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('IsDefaultEmailAddress',false);
                    } 
               
                jsonGen.writeEndObject();
                jsonGen.writeEndArray();
                    if(con.Preferred_Contact_Method__pc != null) {
                      jsonGen.writeObjectField('PrfrdCommMediumType','INT');
                    }
                    else {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('PrfrdCommMediumType','INT');
                    } 
               
                jsonGen.writeEndObject();
                jsonGen.writeEndArray();
                jsonGen.writeFieldName('to_BuPaIdentification');
                jsonGen.writeStartArray();
                if(con.Emirates_ID_Number__pc != null) {
                    System.debug('PASSPORT NTTEE ' + con.Passport_No__c );
                jsonGen.writeStartObject();
                jsonGen.writeObjectField('BPIdentificationType','FS0001');
                jsonGen.writeObjectField('BPIdentificationNumber',con.Emirates_ID_Number__pc);
                     if(con.Nationality__pc != null) {
                      jsonGen.writeObjectField('Country',mapOfCountryNameToCountrycode.get(con.Nationality__pc));
                    }
                    else {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('Country','AE');
                    } 
               
                jsonGen.writeEndObject();
                }
                if(con.Passport_No__c != null) {
                    System.debug('PASSPORT NTT' );
                jsonGen.writeStartObject();
                jsonGen.writeObjectField('BPIdentificationType','FS0002');
                jsonGen.writeObjectField('BPIdentificationNumber',con.Passport_No__c);
                     if(con.Nationality__pc != null) {
                      jsonGen.writeObjectField('Country',mapOfCountryNameToCountrycode.get(con.Nationality__pc));
                    }
                    else {
                    jsonGen.writeObjectField('Country','AE');
                    } 
                jsonGen.writeEndObject();  
                }
                
                jsonGen.writeEndArray();
                }
                 jsonGen.writeEndObject();
                
                 jsonData = jsonGen.getAsString();
                 System.debug('Json Data - ' + jsonData);
                 req.setBody(jsonData);
                 system.debug('CC ID');
                 Http http = new Http();
                 HttpResponse response = http.send(req);
                 sYSTEM.debug('STATUS CODE ' + response.getStatusCode());
                 String jsonString = response.getBody().replaceAll('\n','').replaceAll('\r','');    
                 Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonString);  
                    
                 if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                    System.debug('SUCCESS ' + response.getBody());
                    String partnerid = (String)results.get('id');
                    con.Partner_Id__c = partnerid;
                    con.SAP_Error__c = false;
                    accntLst.add(con);
                 }
                 else {
                       System.debug('FAILURE ' + response.getBody());
                       con.SAP_Error_Response__c = jsonString;
                       con.SAP_Error__c = true; // on update of this boolean i need to throw error(ie at lead conversion point i am sending this account to external point)
                       accntLst.add(con);
                     
                }
            }
         
          update accntLst;
            
           
           
        }
   
     
     
     

  }
}
```

Please help me on this

Comment: See the document from Salesforce. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_exceptions.htm

Answer (score 1):

Callouts happen after a transaction completes. You can't show an error to the user, because the error has not happened yet. Adding an error here would only serve to prevent the record from saving. If you really want to send a message, do so in a Chatter message using the [Connect API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_connect_api.htm) or some other means, they'll get a bell notification in the UI.

Comment: hi sfdcfox, I have edited my post , added the integration code also. Can u pls check

Comment: @AthiraVenugopalAphidas As I stated, future methods happen after the main transaction. What I see of your integration code confirms what I already guessed you were doing. As I said, you can't add the error anywhere because the transaction that completed has already returned back to the user. You need to notify them asynchronously.